# Tooltip Issue with ie6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have a tooltip which is having pseudo classes.
And working fine on all the browser.

But it is not working on ie6. I dont know if it is not working because of pseudo class. 
Can I get any help to make the this work on ie6.

```
span.tooltip {
    padding:0 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:100;
    padding-top:2px
}
span.tooltip > span {
    display:none;
    background:#E4E8EF;
    top:-79px;
    left:18px;
    position:absolute;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #BAC0C9;
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px #CAC9C9;
    z-index:100;
}
span.tooltip span b {
    display:block;
    width:262px;
    font-weight:normal;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px;
    line-height:18px;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#1C3A54;
    font-size:12px
}
span.tooltip span b:before {
    display:block;
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:10%;
    top:-30px;
    z-index:200;
}
span.tooltip:hover {
    position:relative;
    z-index:100;
}
span.tooltip:hover > span {
    display:block;
}

<span onmouseover="void(0)" class="tooltip"><img src="https://javasite.zones.internal/images/global/checkout/icon_question.png"><span><b>What you put in the Alias field will appear on the Ship To Address drop down list on your account so you can locate this address for future use.</b></span></span>
```

Thanks

Comment: before and after pseudo classes aren't supported in IE7 and lower.

Comment: This may not help solve the question but why are you still using or supporting IE6?

Comment: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @henrywright Required to fix IE6. :(

Comment: @RohitMehra you will need to either implement alternative css/markup to be served to IE6/7 that doesn't use psuedoelements, or use a javascript polyfill of some kind to create backwards compatibility for them.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your guidance.

Comment: @rohit-mehra Fair enough